Getting error "Error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out : ``" when trying to run command compose
When I use command "docker compose -f mysql.yml -p nodejs-sql up -d". I got this error "[+] Running 0/0

db-mysql Pulling                                                                                                0.1s
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-wincred.exe": executable file not found in %PATH%, out: ```"

I was searched on google but havent get any solution

Docker: Unable login to Docker Hub from Windows seems to discuss the error message, does that help you?  (Just searching for the executable name in the error message was fruitful for me.)
